# jquery - attach .click() to multiple variables

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following code:

```
var buttonOne = $("#buttonOne");
var buttonTwo = $("#buttonTwo");

// opens an already initialized modal window 
(buttonOne, buttonTwo).click(function()
{
    modalBoxContainer.dialog("open");
});
```

This is not working.  It will work if I use the elements, but not with the variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you missing the $?  your example is.

Comment: I was but that does not make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try combining the selector?

```
$("#buttonOne, #buttonTwo").click(...
```

Although you should really use `on` (jQuery 1.7) or `delegate` for pre-1.7, this will create the one event for all elements in the handler. Something like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonOne, #buttonTwo", function () {
    //function here
});
```

`on` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

`delegate` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: I wouldn't use "delegated" events for this.  They are "live" events, which I don't think is really needed here. `$("#buttonOne, #buttonTwo").click` is the way to go.

Comment: Well with the delegate you'll only have 1 event, with the click you'll have one for each element wouldn't you? :)

Comment: @mattytommo true, however any time you click anywhere in the document it's going to have to check the `event.target` against those two ids.

Comment: @KevinB Arguably a better overhead than having duplicate events though? :)

Comment: i'm leaning towards just using two selectors ($("#buttonOne, #buttonTwo").click(...), but is there a benefit to first assigning the selectors to a variable vs. directly using the selectors for .click()?

Comment: @taulant no benefit unless you are using the individual cached elements elsewhere

Comment: @taulant as Kevin said, there's no benefit putting them in a variable unless you're using them elsewhere :)

Comment: @taulant or if you are using them elsewhere, it'd still be faster just to replicate that selector with your cached objects using `$("#" + buttonOne.attr("id") + ", " + "#" + buttonTwo.attr("id"))`

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate your insight and help on this. I think Kevin's and mattytommo's solutions work, but I'll use the multiple selectors for what I need atm.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method.

```
buttonOne.add(buttonTwo).click(...);
```

Comment: FYI combined selector is approximately 42% faster than `add` Source: http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-add/5

Comment: Agreed, but what if the selectors aren't available to be combined?

Comment: He already has both elements cached, how does that affect the outcome of the jsperf, assuming that the cached selections aren't used but have already been made?

Comment: Based on the fact that his only usage of the objects is in the event declaration in the given code, arguably it's overhead that he's got those variables in the first place. That's unless he has omitted code that uses said variables of course.

Comment: Plus if he did use them, arguably using `$("#" + buttonOne.attr("id") + ", " + "#" + buttonTwo.attr("id"))` would still be faster than `add`

Comment: That doesn't include my second suggestion building it with the cached object ids :)

Comment: @Kevin B: selector could be retrieved by .selector

Comment: @Homer if you are referring to the jsperf, that wouldn't give an accurate test, the .add would obviously be faster than selecting by an id and .find on a classname (as demonstrated by test2). jsperf results are useless in this case though because all of the results are so close in performance that the difference is negligible and a waste of time to argue about.

Comment: not refering to jsperf. It was in response to "what if the selectors aren't available to be combined?" I was just pointing out that you could get the selector by doing `buttonOne.selector`. In this case, it would return `#buttonOne`